# Why does stacked bar plot change when add facet in r ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have data that are in several groups, and I want to display them in a faceted stacked bar chart. The data show responses to a survey question. When I look at them in the dataframe, they make sense, and when I plot them (without faceting), they make sense.

However the data appear to change when they are faceted. I have never had this problem before. I was able to re-create a change (not the exact same change) with some dummy data.

```
myDF <- data.frame(rep(c('aa','ab','ac'), each = 9),
               rep(c('x','y','z'),times = 9),
               rep(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), each=3, times=3),
               sample(50:200, 27, replace=FALSE))
colnames(myDF) <- c('place','program','response','number')
library(dplyr)
myDF2 <- myDF %>%
    group_by(place,program) %>%
    mutate(pct=(100*number)/sum(number))
```

The data in `myDF` are basically a count of responses to a question. The `myDF2` only creates a percent of respondents with any particular response within each place and program.

```
library(ggplot2)
my.plot <-ggplot(myDF2, 
             aes(x=place, y=pct)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=myDF$response),stat="identity")

my.plot.facet <-ggplot(myDF2, 
                   aes(x=place, y=pct)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=myDF$response),stat="identity")+
    facet_wrap(~program)
```

I am hoping to see a plot that shows the proper "pct" for each "response" within each "program" and "place". However, `my.plot.facet` shows only one "response" per place.

[image: example of my.plot and my.plot.facet]

The data are not like that. For example, `head(myDF2)` shows that program 'aa' in place 'x' has both yes and no.

```
> head(myDF2)
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: place, program

  place program response number      pct
1    aa       x      yes     69 18.35106
2    aa       y      yes     95 25.81522
3    aa       z      yes    192 41.64859
4    aa       x       no    129 34.30851
5    aa       y       no    188 51.08696
6    aa       z       no    162 35.14100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ORDER matters here. The myDF2 is not a data frame anymore. It is a dplyr object. That means that ggplot2 is really struggling.

If the data need to be faceted by program, 'program' needs to be first called in the `group_by()`

Note that this is true here by looking at the inverse plot faceting.

```
my.plot.facet2 <-ggplot(myDF2, 
                       aes(x=program, y=pct)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill=myDF2$response),stat="identity")+
   facet_wrap(~place)
```

produces:

[image: my.plot.facet2]